# Shared library missing header file that I know exists

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I have a project structure roughly equivalent to this:

```
>>> ls -R
- whatever
-   libfoo.so
-   foo.h
-   foo.c
-   test2.c
- however
-   test1.c
```

`libfoo.so` is a library, `test.c` is a simple library that right now includes `foo.h` and prints "Hello World!".
I can compile with `gcc test1.c -o test -std=c2x -L/dir/to/lib -lfoo`
But when I attempt to run `test` I get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: liblfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What do I do?

Comment: You are doing `-lfoo` but it is complaining about a missing `liblfoo.so` instead of `libfoo.so`. A typo somewhere?

Comment: @CraigEstey Yeah it's a typo made while refactoring in order to show the example

Comment: Consider using `-rpath` with (or instead of) `-L`

Comment: You can look at `readelf -a test` output to see what directories will be searched.

Comment: @CraigEstey I ran that command but couldn't find any directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your shared library is not in the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**, just put the path of the folder where the **so file** is there in your environment variables, you may want to put it permanently in your bash profile just put the following command in the ".bashrc" file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/the_folder_you_are_working_on/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/the_folder_you_are_working_on/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: If I were somebody publishing a program, what would the appropriate thing to do be?

Comment: @user852541 Is there a reason why you can't link the library statically?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my top comments, use `-rpath` ...

Do the following (e.g.):

```
LIBDIR=/dir/to/lib

gcc test1.c -o test -std=c2x -L$LIBDIR -Wl,-rpath=$LIBDIR -lfoo
```

---

For multiple libraries/directories, here's a sample `Makefile`:

```
LIBS += -lmy
LIBS += -lmy2

TOP = /tmp/myall
DIRS += $(TOP)/mylib
DIRS += $(TOP)/mylib2

PATHL := $(addprefix -L,$(DIRS))

PATHR := $(addprefix :,$(DIRS))
PATHR := $(shell echo $(PATHR) | sed -e s/:/-Wl,-rpath=/g)

test:
    cc -o test test.c $(PATHL) $(PATHR) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f test
```

---

Here is the output of `make`:

```
cc -o test test.c -L/tmp/myall/mylib -L/tmp/myall/mylib2 -Wl,-rpath=/tmp/myall/mylib -Wl,-rpath=/tmp/myall/mylib2 -lmy -lmy2
```

---

Here's a snippet of `readelf -a test`:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x2df0 contains 27 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmy.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmy2.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/tmp/myall/mylib:/tmp/myall/mylib2]
```

Note that if we omit `-rpath`, the `RPATH` section of the ELF file will *not* be generated. That is the issue.